# Deploying java Application on cloud using AWS OPSWORK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I am a newbie to aws and am currently under the free usage tier. i was trying to deploy my java application using opswork. As suggested in the demo video at "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NnWJsS4Y2cI" i created a java app server layer and a ha proxy server layer and on top of these layers i added java instances and a loadbalancer instance. Both are running and shown as green . I also Linked the GitHub repository URL that contains the source code for my app and then deployed the app on all the instances. however when i try to access my application using the elastic ip of the load balancer , it throws me a 503 error. Also when i check in my ec2 dashboard, to my surprise i see 0 running instnces. Doesnot creating instances should reflect in the dashboard?? And also help me deal with the 503 error.

I have extensively searched over the web for solution but to no success.
Please help me in this regard. Kindly point out as to where am i going wrong??

Answer (score 1):

## ec2 : No instances running :

That is usually because you either have not refreshed, OR are in the wrong region. At the top right, make sure to go into the right region.

[image: region image]

## If you have already started the AWS EC2 instance and can see something like this :

[image: opsworks layer image]

Click on the specific instance IP. Make sure you can view the website on the ports you're expecting. You need to also configure your ELB seperately to the Opsworks instances. The ELB has to know which ports it has to enable. Check individual layers, and then check the logs of the HA proxy layer. I usually do not use HA proxy unless it's for something AWS does not already support : websocket.

Comment: Yes Imran! I figured it out that the ec2 instances were running in some other region. Thanks for the reply anyways. However, could you tell on the first part as to why am i getting 503 error when trying to access the app through the load balancer ip

Comment: If you see website on the PUBLIC instance IP, but LOAD BALANCER is 503 - your load balancer needs to be configured. EC2 > LOAD BALANCERS > choose the load balancers. Modify it to point to the outside world port ----> instance port. Also check HEALTHCHECK pages that are in use. USE TCP if you want to make sure it works. 404 pages will break ELB Healthchecks. Make sure to also look at the loadbalancer page on Opsworks. To see if the instances appear Ticked or Not.

Comment: now i am configuring the loadbalancer in my network settings of my application server layer. I have actually created a laodbalancer in the same zone and then changed the ports to 8080(as most people suggested). Also made the response timeout as 60 . but still when i try to access the lb, it gives me a connection refused error. i have tried restarting instances also. Please help me as to where am i going wrong!

Comment: I was having a similar issue with my elb and switching the health check to TCP fixed my issue.